# Excel VBA Open a Folder

Tags: vba, excel, directory, excel-2010

Using 2010 Excel VBA - I'm just trying to open a folder through a sub. What am I doing wrong here?

VBA

```
Sub openFolder()  
  Dim preFolder As String, theFolder As String, fullPath as String

    theFolder = Left(Range("T12").Value, 8)
    preFolder = Left(Range("T12").Value, 5) & "xxx"
    fullPath = "P:\Engineering\031 Electronic Job Folders\" & preFolder & "\" & theFolder

    Shell(theFolder, "P:\Engineering\031 Electronic Job Folders\" & preFolder, vbNormalFocus)

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the folder once you've opened it?

Comment: Shell only takes two arguments. as mentioned it's not real clear what you're doing

Comment: I want the user to be able to click a button and the folder opens on the screen - nothing else.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you want to open a windows file explorer, you should call explorer.exe

```
Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & "P:\Engineering", vbNormalFocus)
```

Equivalent syxntax

```
Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "P:\Engineering", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: @d-stroyer, you are close. The line would look something like `shell "explorer.exe /e,z:\MyPath\To\Folder"`

Comment: I think you also need to put the path in quotes if there could be a space in it.

Comment: This can be simplified with `Shell("explorer.exe P:\Engineering", vbNormalFocus)`. With spaces, though, they need to be double-quoted, twice, as Tim mentioned: `Shell("explorer.exe ""P:\Engineering\031 Electronic Job Folders""", vbNormalFocus)`

Answer (score 0):

I use this to open a workbook and then copy that workbook's data to the template.

```
Private Sub CommandButton24_Click()
Set Template = ActiveWorkbook
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .InitialFileName = "I:\Group - Finance" ' Yu can select any folder you want
    .Filters.Clear
    .Title = "Your Title"
    If Not .Show Then
        MsgBox "No file selected.": Exit Sub
    End If
    Workbooks.OpenText .SelectedItems(1)
```

'The below is to copy the file into a new sheet in the workbook and paste those values in sheet 1

```
    Set myfile = ActiveWorkbook
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy after:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    myfile.Close
    Template.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink ("folder path goes here")
```