# Open file folder to specific location through VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to have the end of the macro open where I had just saved the spreadsheet. i am using the shell feature but it is not going to the location i want it is just opening up the file folder to the documents.
this is what i have so far

```
Dim Var as string
Var = "K:Test drive\Open here"
Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & Var, vbNormalFocus)
```

Any idea how i can have it open the exact Path i need?

Comment: [Double quote the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17426704/excel-vba-open-a-folder#comment25318061_17426972)?

Comment: You code works fine for me. I removed the parenthesis: `Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "D:\test\", vbNormalFocus`.  Are you sure that you have the right path?  You should use the workbook reference, if you have one (e.g. `Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Path, vbNormalFocus`).

Comment: it gives me a syntax error if i double quote

Comment: @TinMan i have earlier i the Code it create the path i want it to open and it works.

Comment: @BigBen i updated the question to a better example i am using a variable for the name and the step opens the file folder just not the correct location

Comment: Try `Shell "explorer.exe " & """" & var & """", vbNormalFocus`

Comment: Or even shorter: `Shell "explorer.exe """ & var & """", vbNormalFocus`.